# C# Adding dynamically created objects to List<dynamic> (WinForms app) ERROR: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

So I've created a class of **production_ordered** every object is beeing created on button click, so every time there is created a new object I want this object to append to the list of type **dynamic**.

Below is the code of the class:

```
public class production_ordered
    {
        public string production_time_obj; // A
        public int par_quan; // B
        public int lin_quan; //C
        public string type; //D
        public int ID_prd;
        public int tick_start;

        public void Ordered_prd(string A, int B, int C, string D, int ID, int prd_tick_start_val)
        {
            
            this.production_time_obj = A;
            this.par_quan = B;
            this.lin_quan = C;
            this.type = D;
            this.ID_prd = ID;
            this.tick_start = prd_tick_start_val;
           
        }
       
    }
```

So after calling the constructor **Ordered_prd** in **private void Button_Click** I wrote this lines(also inside **private void Button_Click**) :

```
        var list = new List<dynamic>();
        list.Add(prod);
        list[index] = prod;
        
        index++;
```

The **index** variable is implemented outside of any method/function it is the global variable on the start it equals 0(zero).
So in my mind I thought about the algorythm like this:

1)User clicks on the button

2)Object of class **production_ordered** is beeing created

3. **this** object is beeing assigned to the list[0] cell

4)User clicks on button again and the another object with different attributes values(then prior object) is beeing created

5)**this** object is beeing assigned to the list[1] cell
etc.

But the problem is when I'm clicking on the button 2'nd time (point 4) I'm getting this error:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: ,,Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection"
```

And I'm beeing thrown to the code from the windows app - which stops working.
The following line is beeing highlighted when this error occurs:

```
list[index] = prod;
```

I don't know how to deal with this.
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'll be honest, seems like a global index variable is a bad idea...

Comment: So you are adding prod twice? That doesn't seem like desired outcome, does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you misunderstand how lists work. Given a list `list`, the command `list.Add(prod);` will append `prod` to the end of `list`. The command `list[index] = prod;` is not necessary at all. Just delete it.

Comment: Ok.
So as you wrote I've deleted `list[index] = prod;`.
But this indicates my another question - How can I acces the objects that are stored in the list? Like check their attributes, change the attributes values and so on (just work on them) if `list[index]` approach is completly wrong?

Comment: The `list[index]` approach is not completely wrong. It was just unnecessary in your case, because you had already added `prod` to the list. Of course you can use it to access elements stored in the list. And you can also modify an element in the list with `list[index] = prod;`. But you have to make sure you list has at least length `index+1` before you access `list[index]`.